# XDomainRequest in IE- "fresh" data only in first call

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, refresh, xdomainrequest

I'm using a JSON request to retrieve some stream gage information in a web page I'm developing. For IE compatibility, I am using XDomainRequest. The XDR successfully retrieves data during the first load of the page but subsequent calls (I use windows.setInterval on the page after load) do not return updated information. Clearing the browser cache does nothing, either. The only way the page will load new data is to actually restart IE and load the page. What am I missing??

Here's my XDR code:

```
        //Now Access & Process the NWS Gage Data
        if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
           //Internet Explorer Doesn't support JQuery's getJSON so you must use an alternative method
           // Use Microsoft XDR
           var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
           xdr.open("get", "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=12150800,12167000,12161000,12150400,12138160,12134500,12186000,12155300,12155500&parameterCd=00065");
           xdr.onload = function () {
           //parse response as JSON
           var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
           if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined')
           {
                JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
           }
              array.forEach(JSON.value.timeSeries, function(curGage, i){
                curGageID = curGage.sourceInfo.siteCode[0].value;
                curGageName = curGage.sourceInfo.siteName;
                curGageHeight = curGage.values[0].value[0].value;
                curGageObs = curGage.values[0].value[0].dateTime;
                //Another Internet Explorer quirk. Date format must be changed due to IE's different interpretation
                curGageObs = curGageObs.replace(/\-/g,"/");
                curGageObs = curGageObs.replace(/T/g," ");
                curGageObs = curGageObs.substring(0,curGageObs.length-10);
                var theDate = new Date(curGageObs);

                document.getElementById('u' + curGageID + 'Height').innerHTML = curGageHeight + " Feet";
                document.getElementById('u' + curGageID + 'Date').innerHTML = theDate.toString('M/d/yyyy @ h:mm tt');
                assignNwsStageColor(curGageID, curGageHeight);                    
              });  
           };
            xdr.send();
        } else {           
            $.getJSON("http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=12150800,12167000,12161000,12150400,12138160,12134500,12186000,12155300,12155500&parameterCd=00065", function(data) {                
                  array.forEach(data.value.timeSeries, function(curGage, i){
                    curGageID = curGage.sourceInfo.siteCode[0].value;
                    curGageName = curGage.sourceInfo.siteName;
                    curGageHeight = curGage.values[0].value[0].value;
                    curGageObs = curGage.values[0].value[0].dateTime;
                    var theDate = new Date(curGageObs);

                    document.getElementById('u' + curGageID + 'Height').innerHTML = curGageHeight + " Feet";
                    document.getElementById('u' + curGageID + 'Date').innerHTML = theDate.toString('M/d/yyyy @ h:mm tt');
                    assignNwsStageColor(curGageID, curGageHeight);                    
                  });                

            });
        }
```

Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that you don't get cached information from an ajax call, you could append a timestamp to the url.

For example:

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com?param1=asdf&_=" + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest but, in this case, it makes the XDR request returns an "unrecognized keyword" error and no return data. Just to be clear, this is not an issue in Chrome or Firefox (which use the JQuery JSON request option).

Comment: ok, this is a problem of the web service. Usually the timestamp should not be a problem. I'm sorry that I couldn't help you. Maybe the only other solution is to create a proxy service, which forwards the requests to the real web service. In the requests to your proxy service you could pass the timestamp parameter. Furthermore you won't have to use a workaround for IE, since you don't have to use cross-domain ajax-requests anymore.

Comment: I did some subsequent work and marked your original answer as correct. While the USGS server would not accept an add-on parameter like you suggested, it did have a valid parameter for starting time. I ended up taking the current date/time in Epoch, subtracting 3 hours from that, and then passing that as the starting date/time.

Now my URL is always unique and, thus, returns non-cached information in IE. Thanks again!